# How can I make git diff return an error if it can't find the file?

Tags: git

I often use git diff to compare my local file with the last check-in, as follows:

```
git diff -- HEAD [name_of_file]
```

Annoyingly, if I happen to mistype the file name, git simply returns empty, indicating no change, instead of telling me it can't find the file, forcing me to scrutinize the file name for errors. Is there a way to make it tell me the file doesn't exist?

Comment: In the above, `HEAD` is on the wrong side of the `--`. The `--` in `git diff` (and in a lot of Git commands) separates options and their arguments from pathspecs or other non-option arguments; it's required when the pathspec could be mistaken for an option (for instance, what if you had a *file* named `HEAD`?). Since `git diff` says nothing about files that don't exist, and you're asking for a diff about the file named `HEAD` which doesn't exist, the `HEAD` here gets ignored. Note that `git diff` defaults to comparing index vs working tree, and the index often matches `HEAD`...

Comment: FWIW : the best tool I know to counter my "twisted fingers" condition is autocomplete : I often rely on `<tab>` to make sure I didn't mistype the beginning of a file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version is "you can't" so you'll need some auxiliary code (e.g., a small wrapper script).

Note that when running:

```
git diff HEAD -- file
```

there are in fact *two* files involved: `HEAD:file` (the copy in the current commit), and `file` (the copy in the working tree).  One of these two can be missing, representing "files is new" or "file is deleted" depending on which one is absent and which one is present.

To find out whether `HEAD:file` exists, use:

```
git rev-parse HEAD:file
```

e.g.:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD:Makefile
56b3d3c5396e5983497c6c26e1a6f4dd3750a0d3
$ git rev-parse HEAD:Makefoil
fatal: path 'Makefoil' does not exist in 'HEAD'
```

If the above error message is sufficient, you can just use:

```
git rev-parse HEAD:$path || exit
```

in a shell script at this point: the `fatal` error goes to stderr, and the nonzero (failure) status from `git rev-parse` causes the shell to go on to evaluate the `||` clause, which exits with the status already in `$?` (whatever nonzero exit status `git rev-parse` produced).  If the rev-parse succeeds, you get the hash ID printed to stdout (so you might want to redirect that to `/dev/null`) and the success status prevents evaluating the `exit` command.

Add `--quiet --verify` to suppress error messages:

```
$ git rev-parse --quiet --verify HEAD:Makefoil
$ git rev-parse --quiet --verify HEAD:Makefile
56b3d3c5396e5983497c6c26e1a6f4dd3750a0d3
```

The exit status from the failed `rev-parse` is still nonzero, so `if git rev-parse --quiet --verify HEAD:$path >/dev/null; then <file exists case>; else <file does not exist case>; fi` works here, for instance.

Remember to quote the expansion of `$path` if it might contain shell metacharacters.

To test whether a file exists locally, use the `test` program (alternately spelled `[`: when run as `[` it demands a closing `]` at the end) with the `-e` (file exists) option:

```
$ if test -e Makefile; then echo exists; fi
exists
$ if [ -e Makefoil ]; then echo exists; fi
```

If you'd like to compare the working tree version of some file against the *index* version of that file, use `git diff -- $path` and convert the rev-parse test to using `:$path` rather than `HEAD:$path`.  To compare `HEAD` vs `index`, use `git diff --cached -- $path` (and you can rev-parse both `HEAD:$path` and `:$path`).

In all cases, remember that `git diff` is a *porcelain* command, so it obeys the user's configuration selections (e.g., when and whether to use a pager, whether to display colorized output, and so on).  Use `git diff-files` or `git diff-index` to get *plumbing* commands that do not obey user configurations and are therefore predictable and machine-usable.

Comment: I think `-f` is a better flag here than `-e` because the user might have a `Makefoil` directory. Relating to the existence guard mentioned: `if [ -e Makefoil]; ...`

Comment: @OrenIshShalom: Well, yes, or maybe no: it all depends on what, if anything, the user wants to have happen if that's a directory. Note that `rev-parse` on `HEAD` will find directories (the found object will have type `tree`) so it's a bit more work to reject directories present in the `HEAD` commit. However, `rev-parse` on the index won't find directories (!) so you get something inconsistent either way.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough explanation. I am no git expert, and the distinction between porcelain and plumbing commands was new to me.

Comment: @AaronHaspel: Git itself isn't always self-consistent here. For instance `git status` is porcelain unless given the `--porcelain[=<version>]` option. Other commands are fully one or the other, e.g., rev-list is plumbing, log is porcelain ... but `git log` can do a few things `git rev-list` can't so either rev-list needs beefing up or log needs a `--porcelain` option like `git status`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git diff HEAD <path>`. But there are downsides:

1. if you have the branch with the same name as the filename, then the error will occur (but you will get different error message compare to when the file is not found).
2. you can actually misspell the filename to the branch name and still get some diff (the diff between commits)

You can fix it, by running:

`git diff HEAD <path> || git diff HEAD -- <path>`

About fixing listed problems. 1. problem is solved by showing the error. 2. problem you should be able to see the difference between the `diff HEAD <commit>` and `diff HEAD <path>`. And of course your problem is solved, you will only see the error.

If you are fine with such solution, then you can simplify it, by adding the alias to the config:

`git config --global alias.diff2 '!git diff HEAD $1 || git diff HEAD -- $1'`

And then just run `git diff2 <path>`

---

Instead of running the above solution you can change execution to:

`git diff HEAD <path> ; git diff HEAD -- <path>`

But, please make note, that this introduce the duplication in case there are no errors in first command. That being said, you can improve this solution by making more complex .sh script to take care of said duplication, and of the 2. problem case (as you would see only one output in such case)